# Button not clickable in selenium, with no error message

Tags: python, selenium

[Picture of error on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suTlg.png)

Whenever my code gets to the last line of code, it clicks the convert button which converts a youtube music video to a mp3 file (don't worry I'm doing it with non-copyrighted music), however only the website itself comes up with an error of: Invalid Argument below the button in a red box. I have tried other formats like .send_keys(Keys.ENTER) or .submit(), but they all get rejected to same way. I don't recommend clicking on the 2nd website with the button, as it has some suspicious adds, hence why I'm using brave instead of Chrome. I would be insanely grateful if anyone takes the time give suggestions as I have been at it for hours and on my last leg.

HTML code for the button:

```
<button id="cvt-btn" class="btn btn-danger mr-1">Convert</button>
```

Full code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

driver_path = "C:/Users/User/Documents/Python_Projects/chromedriver.exe"
brave_path = "C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe"
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=option)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkNeIUgNPQ8&list=PLzCxunOM5WFLNCSF0UEHZqFJJlmdeL71S")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-consent-bump-v2-lightbox/tp-yt-paper-dialog/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/ytd-button-renderer[2]/a/tp-yt-paper-button").click()
lnks=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
songs = []
double = False
for lnk in lnks:
   link = lnk.get_attribute("href")
   if link != None:
       if "FJJlmdeL71S&index=2" in link:
           for i in songs:
               if link == i:
                   double = True
               else:
                   double = False
           if double == False:
               songs.append(link)

driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.get("https://youtubetomp3music.com/en26/")

for i in songs:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input").send_keys(i)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button").click()        
    driver.find_element_by_id("cvt-btn").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not run your program fully, so I do not know what **exactly** is stored in `songs` list.

Below code is from the moment when you do this `driver.get("https://youtubetomp3music.com/en26/")`, I am doing

```
driver.get("https://youtubetomp3music.com/en26/download?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DgrL4JMs0hDc%26list%3DRDgrL4JMs0hDc%26start_radio%3D1")
```

to just to reach the end page so that we can click on **Convert button.**

**Code :-**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://youtubetomp3music.com/en26/download?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DgrL4JMs0hDc%26list%3DRDgrL4JMs0hDc%26start_radio%3D1")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id='cvt-btn']"))).click()
```

**Imports** :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still runs into the same error message of "invalid argument" on the website. I tried using the code on both chrome and brave as browsers, as well as other IDEs. If it worked for you then I'm utterly baffled, however if it doesn't, then I'm starting to think the website has some anti-automation system in place. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to answer, I really appreciate it. Your response was really well laid out, explained, and easy to follow. I would upvote if I had enough reputation xD.

Comment: As mentioned above, I did not go to youtube at first place, instead I directly hit the converter web site, and they do have anti bot installed so you need proxy or something else to get rid of that, once you do that it would be easy to make the script work, the above code should work for you.

Comment: Alas it seems I can't seem to get tor to work on selenium, and I'm not really sure if I can trust other proxies, at least this time I know the problem. Anyway thanks for the quick response, it seems due to the anti bot its a lost cause. I guess your comment to the answer was the solution, so I will accept the answer? Not sure that's how it works, but your the same person. Anyway, I hope you have a great day :)

Comment: This ticket is for button that wasn't clickable, now my answer I believe that it resolves your query regarding click of the button. Anyway have a good day ahead !